# combine variable loop apex

Tags: loop

I have a simple question:

I have a loop that iterate on an integer i.

each loop iteration i becomes i+1

I have another set of variables : x1, x2, x3, x4 etc

I would like at each iteration of the loop to do something like :

x+i = i

The goal is therefore to have 
x1=0 
x2=1
x3=2
...

When I do x+i=i I have an error

What would be the correct call to have the right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make "x" an array indexed by "i" and do:

```
Integer[] x = new Integer[maxI];

for (Integer i = 0; i < maxI; i++) {
    x[i] = i;
}
```

You could, of course, ignore x[0] and do x[i + 1] = i instead to better align with your x1 = 0, x2 = 1 etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was helpful @PhilW
and then if I want to replace it later on in a body with : 
body = body.replace('{!x[i]},x[i])  will that work out or should I do another loop ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're doing here. Note that x[i] will (at least initially and if you don't actually modify the value after you first set up the array) necessarily be the same as i. If you're in a Visualforce page you can use apex:repeat to iterate. If you're in Apex you'd use a for loop like "for (Integer value : x)" to iterate across all the entries.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW, I will create a new post to explain properly my implementation problem but it is nice to see members like you here. ;)